# Import Excel data to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, import, openrowset

I want to insert the data from excel file into the SQL Server..
I used the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                  'Excel 8.0;Database=Y:\Path.xls',
                  'SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]')
```

But i am getting the following error -

> Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" has not been registered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Import data wizard of SQL Server instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server version>=2005 you can use management studio or SSIS.

check the link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Try running this:

```
USE [tableName]
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO
```

in your query

and use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" , works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to import the data in SQL from Excel. Just you need to understand that you have to add a library in VBA and only then you will use below code.
Go in VBA and then add reference – Microsoft ActiveX Data objects 2.8 Library.

```
Sub sbADOExample()
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
'DBPath ="C:\InputData.xlsx"
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
Conn.Open sconnect
sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$]" ' Your SQL Statement (Table Name= Sheet Name=[Sheet1$])
mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
'=>Load the Data into an array
'ReturnArray = mrs.GetRows
''OR''
'=>Paste the data into a sheet
Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
'Close Recordset
mrs.Close
'Close Connection
Conn.Close
End Sub
```